# Getting address to a member function inside the member function

Tags: c++

I would like to get the address of a member function inside the same member function. The this pointer is acquired already so I know which object I am called from. Of course the compiler complains that I'm trying to use a pointer to this function while not calling it. I see the point for having this rule outside an object. Is there no way to get "MY OWN" (the functions address when it is called) address?

This is only for debugging purposes and should be used in a macro. It would be great to have a way to do this.

Code to clarify:

```
class A
{
    void do_stuff()
    {
        printf("0x%X\n", (void*)(this->do_stuff));
    }
};
```

This is on an embedded system I do not get why there is absolutely no way to get the address where do_stuff is saved in flash.

Edit I tried getting the "pointer to member function" like this:

```
printf("CAPP::TASK 0x%08X\n", &CApp::Start);
```

It gives me 0x08013E85 which I look up in my linker map and it is exactly the function I am looking for. This is mdk-arm using Keil µVision 5 as a compiler. Is this correct?

Edit 2:
All kinds of type casts give me invalid type conversion. Although printf's output is correct: Printf uses variadic macros. Let's rebuild that:

```
uint32_t getAdr(uint32_t n, ...)
{
    uint32_t adr=0;
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl,n);
    adr=va_arg(vl,uint32_t);
    va_end(vl);
    return adr;
}

#define GetAdr(x) getAdr(0,&x);

void CApp::Start()
{  
    uint32_t a = GetAdr(CApp::Start);
    printf("Adr: 0x%08X\n", a);
    ...
}
```

Nasty hack, but it worked. But why does this work? Sadly I don't have the implementation of __va_arg(...). How does __va_arg typecast values to the given type? Is there a way to use that feature somehow?

Comment: The thing you're asking for doesn't exist. There are no such things as "object member functions". There are only class member functions.

Comment: Your question's very unclear.  Why don't you show the code that you've tried that best expresses what you're trying to achieve...?  You might also want to read through http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html.  For debugging, you might want to log `__func__` - quite a different thing to an address.

Comment: Could you post some [pseudo]code to clarify your question ?

Comment: The last edit gives me the correct address but how does printf even read the input as I get the warning that the parameter is incompatible. How can I cast &CApp::Start to anything like void* or uint32_t?

Comment: when I do what is described in the link I get an invalid type conversion. My compiler (MDK-ARM) does not seem to support that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pointer-to-member function is generally twice the size of a normal pointer like a `void*` so there is no direct conversion possible in standard C++.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Bound-member-functions.html documents a GCC extension which allows you to get a normal (non-member) function pointer by combining `this` and `&CApp::Start` (that page also explains why a pointer to member function has additional info beyond just the function address).

That extension could be used like so:

```
typedef void (*pf_type)(CApp*);
pf_type pf = (pf_type)&CApp::Start;
```

I would guess that your hack with `va_arg` works because your compiler represents the pointer-to-member-function `&CApp::Start` as a double-word object, with the function address in one of the words, which you read via the varargs hack because two words get pushed onto the stack and then you only read one of them.  You might be able to get similar results using a union:

```
union dirty_hack
{
  void (CApp::*pmf)();
  uint32_t words[2];
};
dirty_hack x;
x.pmf = &CApp::Start;
printf("Adr: 0x%08X\n", x.words[0]);   // might need to be x.words[1] instead
```

You can generalise that using a template:

```
template<typename F>
uint32_t
getaddr(F f)
{
  union dirty_hack
  {
    F pmf;
    uint32_t words[2];
  };
  dirty_hack x;
  x.pmf = f;
  return x.words[0];   // might need to be x.words[1] instead
}

printf("Adr: 0x%08X\n", getaddr(&CApp::Start));
```

N.B. it would be better to use `uintptr_t` not `int32_t` for portability to systems where pointers are not 32-bits, although this sort of hackery is inherently non-portable (the union trick above relies on type-punning, which is undefined behaviour but supported by some compilers).

Comment: sounds great but: error:  #415: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "void (app::CApp::*)()" to "dirty_hack" :(

Comment: oops, sorry, I wasn't thinking straight - I've fixed the code so it should work now.

Comment: great that seems to work, but a problem here is that you need to give the exact function definition inside the union.

Comment: Jeez, do I have to do everything myself? ;) answer updated with a function template to handle any type

Comment: damnit I didn't even think that far! thanks this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "this object's member function." The member functions are effectively *shared* by all objects of the same class - it's just code, not data. `this` is usually passed as an extra hidden parameter to these functions.

In effect, the compiler transforms this:

```
struct Obj
{
  int a;

  int foo(int x) const { return x * a; }
};

int bar(const Obj &o)
{ return o.foo(42); }
```

into something like this:

```
struct Obj
{
  int a;

  static int foo(const Obj *this, int x) { return this->x * a; }
};

int bar(const Obj &o)
{ return Obj::foo(&o, 42); }
```

As you can see, there's no such thing as "`&(o.foo)`". All instances of `obj` have the same `foo`.

In addition, C++ does not give you access to this "staticised `foo`", precisely because it's an implementation detail and compilers could do it differently if they so choose (or if the platform dictates it). The best you can get is the pointer-to-member to the function, `&Obj::foo`. Of course, this is not a real address, it's more like an offset within the class `Obj`. And you need to spell out its name explicitly - there's no way to refer to "the enclosing function" without using its name.

The best you can get without naming the function is the predefined variable `__func__` (introduced in C++11), which contains some compiler-specific form of the function's name.

Comment: Okay all instances have the same foo, that is perfect but how can I get the address of foo while I'm running foo. No matter who called it.

Comment: @clambake `&Obj::foo` gives you the member pointer, which you should read up on because they are unlike other pointers. You won't be able to pass it to `printf`.

Comment: I know that there is a different type of pointer in c++. And there is absolutely no way of getting the plain address?

Comment: `__func__` is not possible since my compiler does not support C++11, sadly.

Comment: @clambake it's likely that your compiler does support *some* method for the function name. Boost has a [nice macro definition](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/boost/current_function.hpp) for the most verbose `__func__` equivalent which works on quite a few compilers. If you don't want boost dependency, just copy the header file.